# How to trigger webhook events from the Stripe dashboard when using ngrok?

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to know if there is a way to trigger webhook events from the Stripe dashboard when using a hosted endpoint with ngrok or any other tunneling tool. Specifically, I am interested in the 'event.subscription.deleted' event, which is triggered on the last date of the billing period when a subscription is canceled. Currently, I see no way to initiate this event directly from the dashboard. So it means I have to wait until the end of the month for the event to trigger, and my manager won't appreciate me waiting for that long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use Test clocks feature via the dashboard to test this: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks

You can advance the clock time and test various things with the subscription cycle.